# error code p2032 using prisma orm on sql db

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

## hey im usuing prisma 3.14 and after changing one property of my schema from int to string i receive that error

```
throw new PrismaClientKnownRequestError(message, e.code, this.client.\_clientVersion, e.meta);

PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.models.findMany()` invocation in


export const getAllModels = async () => {const resUnparsed = await prisma.models.findMany(

Error converting field "campaign_id" of expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "9156".
at Object.request (/home/shay/nbo-mvp/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/insait/runtime/index.js:45405:15)

at async PrismaClient.\_request (/home/shay/nbo-mvp/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/insait/runtime/index.js:46301:18) {
code: 'P2032',

clientVersion: '3.14.0',

meta: { field: 'campaign_id', expected_type: 'String', found: '9156' }
```

im not sure how to approach it since prisma documentation does not have this error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your field `campaign_id` field is stored as an integer in the database, while you specified a `String` in your `prisma.schema`. You can check that by making a query directly in the db (e.g. in Postgresql):

```sql
select pg_typeof( campaign_id ) from your_table;
```

You might need to migrate first:

```
npx run prisma migrate dev
```

Which will tell you in case of desynchronization

Comment: thank you i have figure dout that when i implemented the demo info it was stil a number and i changed it thanks